# Validate JS script block within an HTML file in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, validation

Is there a way to have eclipse validate javascript within a `<script>` block on an HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a plugin you can use that will do so. I use Aptana Studio, and it shows validation errors.